# How to input a two-dimensional array in one loop?

Tags: c#, arrays

My teacher gave me today this mission, to built a code block in c# that input data to a two-dimensional array, in only one loop.

What is the easiest way to do so? I tried some thing with While and they didn't work at all.

Comment: Hint: Use for and modulo

Comment: It's not really clear what's needed here.  At its simplest, you can loop through one dimension and just add static arrays to the data structure in that loop.  But what does that really accomplish?  Can you clarify perhaps with some attempted examples or pseudo-code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If your teacher gave you this I'm guessing  giving away the answer is a bit easy!

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: More substantial hint: run `for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) Console.WriteLine(i % 10);` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a counter that is the length of the first array, a counter for the length of the second array.  Then increment each as you seed the arrays appropriately.  I'm not sure you want actual code since this is an assignment.

You can use a `while` loop that checks for the counters to be a certain length to know when the arrays are finished being loaded with data.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your teacher wants to learn about modulo division operator (`%`).  If your two dimensions are of sizes `X` & `Y` respectively, then you have a total of `X*Y` items in your 2D array.  So you can always translate item's count into it's position in 2D array.  E.g. (in pseudo code):

```
for(int i = 0; i < X*Y; ++i)
{
    myArray[i%x, i/x] = i;
}
```